Altair: add a line in a grouped bar chart
I have this data that I want to plot. In column 'IPVA' there are [0, 1, 2] as possible values, where 1 and 0 are the data that I want to plot as a grouped bar chart, and the 2 is data that I want to plot as a line above them. Right now I'm using the next code to create both graphics, but when I try to concat them, I get this error, and I don't know how to proceed:

base = alt.Chart(dataset_obj1).encode(x=alt.X('Periodo:N'))

bar = base.mark_bar(color='#2A629A').encode(
    x=alt.X('IPVA:O', axis=None).title('Periodo'),
    y=alt.Y('Total:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 0.38]), axis=alt.AxisConfig(titleColor='#2A629A')).title('IPVA nacional'),
    color='IPVA:N',
    column=alt.Column('Periodo:N', header=alt.Header(orient='bottom'))
).properties(
    width=50,
    height=300,
    title='IPVA en relación al salario medio'
).transform_filter(
    alt.FieldOneOfPredicate(field='IPVA', oneOf=[1, 0])
);

line = base.mark_line(color='red', point=True).encode(
    x=alt.X('Periodo:O'),
    y=alt.Y('Total:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 0.45]), axis=alt.AxisConfig(titleColor='red')).title('Salario medio nacional'),
    color=alt.value('red')
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300,
).transform_filter(
    alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='IPVA', equal=2)
);


(line + bar).resolve_scale(y='independent')



[........]
---> 28 (line + bar).resolve_scale(y='independent')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\mt_python\Lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v5\api.py:1240, in TopLevelMixin.__add__(self, other)
   1238 if not isinstance(other, TopLevelMixin):
   1239     raise ValueError("Only Chart objects can be layered.")
-> 1240 return layer(self, other)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\mt_python\Lib\site-packages\altair\vegalite\v5\api.py:3087, in _check_if_can_be_layered(spec)
   3085     for channel in ["row", "column", "facet"]:
   3086         if _get(encoding, channel) is not Undefined:
-> 3087             raise ValueError(
   3088                 "Faceted charts cannot be layered. Instead, layer the charts before faceting."
   3089             )
   3090 if isinstance(spec, (Chart, LayerChart)):
   3091     return

ValueError: Faceted charts cannot be layered. Instead, layer the charts before faceting.

Can someone help me, I want to do something like this but with the grouped bars:

Thank you!
I tried to concat the graphs, create both graphics in a base, but I couldn't get what I want.

The error message points you in the right direction: you need to do faceting after layering. For your spec, that means replacing the column encoding with a .facet method on the layered spec. See this section of the docs for an example https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#faceted-charts

The solution you are proposing will give me split graphs with each pair of bar comparing, but that makes the total graphic a little messy... I would want to keep the same organization as I told above...

base = alt.Chart(dataset_obj1).encode(x=alt.X('Periodo:N'))
bar = base.mark_bar(color='#2A629A').encode(
    x=alt.X('Indice:O', axis=None).title('Periodo'),
    y=alt.Y('Total:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 0.38]), axis=alt.AxisConfig(titleColor='#2A629A')).title('IPVA nacional'),
    color='Indice:N',
    #column=alt.Column('Periodo:N', header=alt.Header(orient='bottom'))
).properties(width=50, height=300,
    title='IPVA en relación al salario medio'
).transform_filter(
    alt.FieldOneOfPredicate(field='Indice', oneOf=['IPVA', 'IPV'])
).facet(
   column='Periodo:N'
)


@RafaRoman Oh I see, you're only using faceting for the bar chart. The easiest would probably be to remove faceting for the bar chart and use the Offset channel to create the grouped bars instead as in this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html

You saved my life! That was the solution! Thank you so much, I used offset and it worked!
